# How do I save a discord.File object to file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How do I save a discord.File object to a file like screenshot.png. I have tried opening a file object and writing to that file but there is no error and no output.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to download an image attachment from a message? Or are you trying to download your own image? Because [discord.File](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.File) is for sending files, not receiving them

Comment: nevermind i found how to do it, using discord.Attachment